# Should I use Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

As the title states:

**Should I use Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?**

See, the dilemma here is the usability. I have to develop a website for a client, and I've been running into quite a bit of difficulty with Drupal 7. A module not working there, an error displaying here, no available 7.x versions for needed modules and so on.
So, can anyone provide some concise points, to why I *should*, or *should not* use Drupal 7?

A list of Pros and Cons would be awesome too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to develop and keep the maintenance minimum, stick to Drupal 6. It has been tested extensively by community and the API documentation is complete (So is Drupal 7s but with [bugs](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=documentation&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All)). Even if you want to use the modules available, most of them are not going to be stable until a few months from now on. I am planning to make the switch at least 6 months after the release date, being the middle of this year. That is the great thing about Drupal: Upgrading is always supported and you never have to make an installation from scratch.

I'd suggest to keep an eye on the current bugs that are marked [major](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=4&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All) and [critical](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=1&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All) and then decide

Answer (score 4):

I recommend listening to the [Lullabot Podcast on the subject](http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/podcast-90-drupal-7-are-you-ready). Their [upgrade chart](http://www.lullabot.com/sites/lullabot.com/files/D7UpgradeChart.png) provides some useful questions to ask when trying to decide.

Answer (score 3):

We are sticking with D6 for the time being.  We are waiting for the Views and Panels modules to settle down some, and will then re-evaluate.

I think it really depends on whether you are making a site for yourself, or are making sites for clients who are paying a flat fee.  On flat-fee projects, D7 is still a bit of a risk until modules become more mature.