# Would you use drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Do you think that it is a good time to start using drupal 7 already? (I am mainly worried about modules. it seems that some important modules are not yet ported to drupal 7) Or stick with 6? Just need your personal opinion.

Comment: Asked and answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837193/should-i-use-drupal-6-or-drupal-7/4838017#4838017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I tried d7 already in autumn and have been looking forward to the release date I since haven't used it yet, mostly because I was enthusiastic about some (private) projects and wanted to see results quickly and in d6 I know what I do and how long it takes.

But in the next days i hopefully have some spare time and mood to start finally with d7. My guess would also be the modules will rise very quickly. (Has anybody an overview about that progress?)

Just go for it, IMO.